# Keycloak Resource Server authorization flow

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm new to Keycloak and trying to find out if authorization services (Resource Server) can fit my requirements.

I have the following scenario: A client app is trying to access my API endpoints which are behind the API gateway.  I want to authenticate (using id and secret) the app and if it's App A allow it access to the endpoint /credits, if it's App B allow it access to the endpoint /debits.

I assume that API gateway should verify if a call should be rejected or not.
Could you please tell me what should my workflow look like and what Keycloak functionality should I use?

Comment: Sorry, you want that App A has access to the resource only if App B has also access to that same resource is that it?

Comment: I want App A has access to /credits resource and as a separate rule App B has access to /debits resource

Answer (score 0):

I'd add roles CREDITS_CLIENT and DEBITS_CLIENT to the API_SERVICE realm in keycloak.

Then, I'd create app-a-service-account and app-b-service-account in that realm, the former with CREDITS_CLIENT role and the later with DEBITS_CLIENT role.

In the gateway or API controller, endpoint /credits requires role CREDITS_CLIENT and endpoint /debits requires role DEBITS_CLIENT.

On each call, check if the details in the jwt include the role that authorizes the account/user to access the endpoint.

Comment: Thanks Eliaquim! Does it mean that I should implement permission verification logic on API Gateway side? Could I do it with authorization request instead? https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_policy_evaluation_overview

Comment: You could implement verification anywhere/how you decide. The most important is to give access according to roles.

If you have an API Gateway, perhaps it's a good decision to verify permissions there, at the gates.